# QQmlExtensionPlugin can't be found

Tags: c++, windows, qt, plugins, qml

I am trying to create a QML Component (QQuickItem) which will receive a URL and display the frames of a rtsp stream over OpenCV.

I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WsW52Iq2aPQ) to create and expose the plugin to my QML view.

Problem when I try to execute, the console says: "module "CVCamScreen" is not installed"

The import into the QML file is being recognized as well. It compiles, but does not run.

Following below is the cvcamscreen project configuration:

**qmldir :**

```
module CVCamScreen
plugin CVCamScreen
```

**cvcamscreen.pro :**

```
TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET = CVCamScreen
QT += qml quick
CONFIG += qt plugin

TARGET = $$qtLibraryTarget($$TARGET)
uri = CVCamScreen

# Input
SOURCES += \
    cvcamscreen_plugin.cpp \
    cvcamscreen.cpp

HEADERS += \
    cvcamscreen_plugin.h \
    cvcamscreen.h

OTHER_FILES = qmldir

!equals(_PRO_FILE_PWD_, $$OUT_PWD) {
    copy_qmldir.target = $$OUT_PWD/qmldir
    copy_qmldir.depends = $$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/qmldir
    copy_qmldir.commands = $(COPY_FILE) \"$$replace(copy_qmldir.depends, /, $$QMAKE_DIR_SEP)\" \"$$replace(copy_qmldir.target, /, $$QMAKE_DIR_SEP)\"
    QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += copy_qmldir
    PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$copy_qmldir.target
}

qmldir.files = qmldir
unix {
    installPath = $$[QT_INSTALL_QML]/$$replace(uri, \\., /)
    qmldir.path = $$installPath
    target.path = $$installPath
    INSTALLS += target qmldir
}

unix:!macx|win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../opencv/build/x86/mingw/lib/ -llibopencv_core249

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../opencv/build/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../opencv/build/include
```

The cvcamscreen project was created under **MyProject\CVCamScreen** which means it is being created under the main project folder.

I am using **QT 5.3** and **Qt Creator 3.1.2 (opensource)** over **Windows 8.1**

**ADITIONAL INFORMATION**

I noticed that the Qt Creator builds the project under a new directory called **build-BSSecurityClient-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MinGW_32bit-debug** and **build-BSSecurityClient-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MinGW_32bit-release**.

I don't know if this is the correct behavior for Qt Creator, but those directories both have another 2 directories called **debug** and **release** inside. Which leaves me the following structure:

```
- build-BSSecurityClient-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MinGW_32bit-debug
    - debug
    - release

- build-BSSecurityClient-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MinGW_32bit-release
    - debug
    - release
```

I might be wrong, but this hierarchy makes no sense to me, as soon as it was specifed a debug and a relase folder, so I see no reason to separate it again.

**QUESTION:** How should I configure this projects to work together?

**EDIT ------------------**

And so I try to import it into the qml file by doing:

```
import CVCamScreen 1.0
```

Comment: Show you C++ code when you import the plugin

Comment: I just import it on QML.

Comment: Solved it by adding a folder containing the libs and qmldir file into the build directory

Comment: @RafaelTSCS what did you name the folder and how did you get the name? Nothing seems to work for me